# TFS - Track when a file was removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and we have Team Foundation Server (I'm not sure which version) running on a server in my office. What I want to do is track when a specific file was removed from a project.

Instance: I was working on one of the older `ASP.NET` web applications and noticed that the `Global.asax` was removed. I have no idea when this happened. I don't want to go through every changeset to see where it was removed because, to date, this particular project has 494 changesets. This might not be a particularly high number, but still too many to investigate one by one.

Alternatively, is it possible to view the state of the entire project at each changeset and not just the changes?

Comment: as far as i remember, i was working with vs2012 and we use to put comments while check in the code. Or you can go through change set details from Source control explorer. But the only possible way that i can see is going through changeset one by one

Comment: @KrunalPatil: Yup, there is the option to add check-in comments, but it's not enforced. And even if it was, the developers around here would probably say something along the lines of: "New update" or "Changed some things"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your visual studio, go to options --> Source Control --> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. Check the option "Show Deleted Items in the Source Control" explorer. You will see the deleted Global.asax file. Right click on it to see history.

Comment: This is perfect, the correct answer. Just, it won't work in some instances like my current one: I've since added a new `Global.asax` to the project and checked it in. Now I only see that version. Hmm. I wonder: if i delete it would it show that and the previous version in the history of the _deleted_ file..

Comment: I see. In that case, have you seen the history of Global.asax file? You will see the full history include deletion. At least this is what I see on VSO

Comment: Yeah, in the history I only see the "versions" of the _new_ file I added sometime after the old file was removed. It shows no evidence that before I added it, a `Global.asax` existed in the project. Though, I tested it by removing my version and adding a new one and I do see both of these versions

Comment: Ahh. I see. At some point the file structure of the solution was changed. The Project I'm working on is in COD -> COD -> Global.asax. At some previous stage all the project files were moved to this location from COD -> COD -> COD -> Global.asax. Then the entire COD folder was removed, wherein I found the _old_ `Global.asax`. Thanks a lot